# A more professional use of "make"

Tags: paraphrasing

How would you paraphrase

"*One of the objectives is to **make** Dubai branch a self-sustaining organization.*"

to make it sound more professional by avoiding the use of "make".

Comment: This is actually fine as-is. A common usage for this sort of thing, however, works on the assumption that the branch will take action on its own, so you'll often see *One of our objectives is to **ensure that the Dubai branch is self-sustaining** by ...*.

Answer (score 0):

You could say :

> "One of the objectives is to **turn** the Dubai branch into a self-sustaining organization."

This would emphasise that it is not now self-sustaining, and that the project to ensure that it does become so is a matter of 'turning it around' an expression commonly used in business for a reparative process.